# Convert one line of VB.Net code to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm looking for the C# equivalent of the line below.

```
If New FileInfo(c:\images\test.jpg).Length < 25 * 1024 Then

'something

End If
```

Thannks for the help.

Answer (score 14):

At least that's a straightforward one.

```
if (new FileInfo(@"c:\images\test.jpg").Length < (25 * 1024))
{
    // something
}
```

The @-sign disables backslash escape processing in the string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out too:  [VB to C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

```
{
    if (new FileInfo("c:\\images\\test.jpg").Length < 25 * 1024) {

    }
    //something
}
```

Be sure to verify the output though.  Converters are not 100%.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (new FileInfo(@"c:\Images\test.jpg").Length < 25 * 1024)
{
  // something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out these free conversion sites for questions like these:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

http://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(new FileInfo(@"c:\images\test.jpg").Length < 1024 * 4))
{
  // something
}
```